# Why complains Haskell parse error on input `|' in this Function?

Tags: haskell, parse-error

I was supposed to write a little function in Haskell, which should erase elements, which are twice in the list. Unfortunately, Haskell complains " parse error on input `|' ". Could anyone help me with that?

```
makeSets=mSet[]s
         where 
            mSet stack []=stack
            mSet stack (x:xs)
                             |contains stack x=mSetstack xs
                             | otherwise =mSet (x:stack) xs
                                          where 
                                                contains [] thing=False
                                                contains (x:xs)thing
                                                                     | x==thing=True
                                                                     |otherwise=contains xs thing
```

Comment: Are you using tabs?  If so, switch to using spaces.  GHC sees tabs as a fixed size, and that fixed size has to meet certain criteria.  You may not have your editor set to that same size, so sometimes you can end up with something that looks syntactically correct but isn't because a column isn't indented far enough for GHC.  Also, you can put the definitions for `mSet` and `contains` in the same `where` clause, you don't need a second one.  Like [this](https://gist.github.com/bheklilr/712420a65d368f9908b6)

Comment: Additionally, your `contains` function is the same as the built-in `elem` function with swapped argument order, and if you really want to make a set then you can import `Data.Set` and just use the `Set` type, which will automatically keep the collection unique for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing tabs and spaces, which is no good when indentation is significant. Use either all spaces (strongly recommended), or all tabs.

Comment: @HerrSchwarz You can set good editors to indent using spaces instead of tab. If you do that, this won't bite you again, and you can still use the tab key as much as you like!

Comment: I was also having this issue but my indentation was fine, I found restarting VSCode solved it