# Why do I get "non-exhaustive patterns in function"?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

In the following code Haskell complains about

```
Non-exhaustive patterns in function prime'
```

```
prime :: Int -> [Int]
prime x = prime' [2..x] where
  prime' (p:ps)= p : prime' [x | x <- ps, mod x p > 0 && prime'' x [2..div x 2]]     
  prime'' _ [] = True
  prime'' n (x:xs)
    | mod n x == 0 = False
    |    otherwise = prime'' n xs

prime' []=[]
```

I can't find my mistake. Could someone explain why this happens, and what it means?

Comment: looks like an indentation issue to me.

Comment: Could you ___please___ provide the code you actually tried? You just changed the indentation of the last line, but the rest of the code isn't indented in a compileable way. By the way, your last edit actually fixed your problem, which kind of invalidates the question.

Comment: fixed one of several problems. There's still weird indentation, and sumDigits is defined but never actually used to filter out unwanted primes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indentation. The last line defines **another function** called `prime'`. Therefore, `prime\prime'` (the definition in the where clause of `prime`) doesn't have a matching pattern for the empty list.

Also, you're indentation is all over the place. Do you still [mix tabs and spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918779/why-complains-haskell-parse-error-on-input-in-this-function)?

Comment: The definition of prime also needs to line up with its type signature. And the two `prime''`'s should be lined up as well.

Comment: @genisage: Since he was able to run his function, not all of those indentation errors can actually be real. I guess some of them happened during the write of the question.

Comment: good point. I wasn't sure which were real and which were transcription errors.

Comment: Thank you ! It was a little identation misstake, which caused the failing of the code.